# Property for specific selector

Tags: css, stylus

### 1. Summary

1. I have list of selectors, to which properties should always apply.
2. For some selectors must be additionally added another properties.

I can't find, how I can do it without duplicates.

---

### 2. MCVE

#### 2.1. Expected CSS

```css
.KiraFirst,
.KiraSecond,
.KiraThird {
  color: red;
}
.KiraSecond {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

In example, I use class `.KiraSecond` 2 times. Can I get expected behavior without this duplicate?

#### 2.2. Stylus

- [**Live demo on stylus-lang.com**](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=.KiraFirst%0A.KiraSecond%0A.KiraThird%0A%09color%20red%0A%0A.KiraSecond%0A%09background-color%20yellow)

```stylus
.KiraFirst
.KiraSecond
.KiraThird
    color red

.KiraSecond
    background-color yellow
```

This is compiled to expected CSS, but I still use `.KiraSecond` 2 times.

I don't understand, how I can not use duplicate. For example, syntax as this not compile to expected CSS:

```stylus
.KiraFirst
.KiraSecond
    background-color yellow
.KiraThird
    color red
```

Result:

```css
.KiraFirst,
.KiraSecond {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.KiraThird {
  color: #f00;
}
```

---

### 3. Not helped

1. [**Stylus official documentation**](http://stylus-lang.com) include [**Selectors section**](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html)
2. [**Stack Overflow Stylus questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylus)
3. [**Stylus GitHub issues**](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues)

Comment: Basically, you can't. What you are asking for is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use basic class for all elements? For example - .Kira and if you need to specify something for other elements you can add extra class .KiraSecond or use .Kira:nth-child(2)

in your example it can be something like this

```
.Kira {
  color: red;
}
.KiraSecond {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

or

```
.Kira {
  color: red;
}
.Kira:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: It's a shame OP hasn't actually shared their HTML structure. I think the only way to achieve their request with no duplication at all is to add a class to the direct parent of all their `.kira*` classes.

Comment: @Scoots well we could also throw `[class^="Kira"]` into the mix here for completeness sake … but that can lead to other issues (specificity), plus what OP wants does probably not make the most sense to begin with.

Comment: @Scoots, it not my own structure, I try overwrite styles for third-party extension ([***Wildfire***](https://wildfire.js.org)), so Solonka solution will not work for me. I need to use duplicates, see [**line 15 and 27**](https://www.pastery.net/sjhgks/#l-27-sjhgks). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You (can't)? and you shouldn't.
Duplicating that selector in that case is not a bad practice.

- you are not duplicating the same property/value for many classes
- you can clearly override specific property
- you can clearly modify/change behaviour for specific class

e.g:

```css
.class1, .class2, .class3 {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.class1:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.class2 {
  border: 2px dotted;
}

.class3 {
  color: pink;
}
```

What would be a bad practice in that case (with no selector duplication)

```css
.class1 {
  color: blue;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.class2 {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px dotted;
}

.class3 {
  color: pink;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```